# No me funciona el spinner

Tags: php, android-studio

como puedo convertir los datos de spinner que son String a int, porque en php y mi base de dato lo toma como int y si no es int no se almacena los datos

Comment: Te sugiero formular mejor tu pregunta, si es posible anexar tu código, explicar mejor el escenario, screenshots, etc.

Comment: Agrega el codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es convertir un String recuperado de un item de un spinner a int prueba lo siguiente

```java
try{
int valorRequerido = Integer.parseInt(tuSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
}catch(Exception e){
Log.e("Error", "El String no contenia solo numero")
}
```

Ojo porque Integer.parseInt() lanza una NumberFormatException cuando el valor no puede ser formateado correctamente. Esto por lo general sucede porque el String no contenía solo números.

Pero sería de gran ayuda que pusieras el código a ver como el adaptador del spinner obtiene los datos.Saludos

Comment: te iba a decir que controles ese error verificando si el String contiene únicamente números …

Comment: También puede hacerse así. A mí en lo particular me gusta tratar el error en caso de que se dé ya q de la otra manera (verificando) siempre verifico aunque no se exista errores y eso incurre en una instrucción más